# Python, find parantheses in a list of list, and return the index, and the parantheses

Tags: python, list, matrix, indexing, find

I try to find all the parantheses (and their contents) in a matrix (lists of lists). I would like to have in a list, the index of parantheses, and the content. For example:
['bla bla bla (' Mr a ') bla', 'bla bla', 'bla bla bla (' Mr b ')]
I would like :
[[0, 'Mr a'], [2, 'Mr b']]
Thank you

Comment: Hey Dan - you might want to post the code that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this :

```
list1 = ['bla bla bla ( Mr a ) bla', 'bla bla', 'bla bla bla ( Mr b )']
res = []
for i in range(len(list1)):
    ind1 = list1[i].find('(')
    ind2 = list1[i].find(')')
    if ind1 < ind2:
        res.append(list1[i][ind1+1:ind2])
print(res)
```

and `print(res)` gives

```
[' Mr a ', ' Mr b ']
```

Comment: yes, it's working, thanks you !